# Constructing a topological space from a chain complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology

I know that given a topological space $X$, I can construct(functorially) the singular chain-complex $C_{\bullet}(X,R)$ (where $R$ is a commutative ring with unit).

I wondered if it was possibile to reverse this construction:

"Starting from a chain complex of $R$-modules $C_{\bullet}$(concentrated at non-negative degrees), can I determine a topological space such that its singular chain complex is isomorphic to $C_{\bullet}$?"

I found out by myself a counterexample:
$$\mathbb{Z}_3 \leftarrow 0  \leftarrow 0  \leftarrow ...$$
Notice that it should be $| \mathbb{Z}_3|=|\mathbb{Z}_3 X|$ that is to say $X$ is a point. But the singular chain complex of a point is different from the one we started with. So there cannot be a topological space that induces the chain complex in the beginning.
So this is not always possible. But I would like to know when this is possible:

**Question 1**

"When does a chain complex (concentrated at non-negative degrees) arise from a topological space? If so, is there a canonical way of constructing this topological space?"

A question that is different, but strictly linked in someway to this one is:

**Question 2**

"Given a succession of $R$-modules $(M_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$, when is it possible to find a topological space $X$ such that its $n$-th homology is isomorphic to $M_n$? If so, is there a canonical way of constructing this topological space?"

I'm interested also in partial(non-trivial) results.

Thank you.

Comment: Please give your counter example

Comment: Your second question has a straightforward answer when $R = \mathbb{Z}$. By taking a product of Eilenberg–MacLane spaces, you can construct a topological space with any combination of singular homology groups you want.

Comment: @Matt I've added it to the question.

Comment: @ZhenLin: do you mean Moore spaces and coproducts? I'm not sure how to find a product of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces whose homology looks like that of $S^2$.

Comment: Err, yes. I must have had homotopy groups and Postnikov towers on my mind…

Comment: @ZhenLin Could you explain me this construction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question 1: This question really can't be interpreted exactly as you ask it since the singular chain complex is so large. It turns out that to turn this into an interesting question with a positive, nontrivial answer, we must restrict coefficients to $\mathbb{Q}$ and also consider the cup product structure on cohomology (or if you really want to work with homology you have to use what is called a coalgebra structure on homology). We must also replace isomorphism with quasi-isomorphism, i.e. a chain map, respecting multiplicative structure (technical difficulties here that I will ignore) that induces isomorphisms on cohomology.

Question 1 is a very classic question and it is answered by rational homotopy theory. The answer is very strong, it is that every rational cochain complex with an algebra structure occurs (up to quasiisomorphism) as the singular chains (correctly interpreted) of some space. In fact, this space is unique up to (rational) homotopy equivalence and it can be picked in a functorial way.

Question 2: One can equip this sequence with trivial differential and trivial multiplication and apply rational homotopy theory to produce such a space. Explicitly, you will get a wedge of Moore spaces (these are spaces with only one nontrivial homology group).

For either of these questions, it becomes much much more difficult if $\mathbb{Q}$ is replace by anything besides another characteristic 0 field. Classifying what cohomology rings occur are classic and presumably still open problems.

Comment: Along the lines of this answer, $p$-adic models of spaces in terms of $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-cochains have been described by Mandell (see e.g., [here](https://mmandell.pages.iu.edu/papers/einffinal.pdf)) and revisited more recently by [Yuan](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.00999), who also describes an integral model.

Comment: Is Question 1 answered by RHT in the non-simply connected case?  When I use RHT, I almost exclusively deal with at-worst nilpotent spaces, so Sullivan models, etc. work just fine.